# Android: using intent without extending activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, extends

I have two classes. FirstActivity and SecondActivity. In the FirstActivity I have something like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Color.class);
    intent.putExtra("keyName","#FFFFFF");
    startActivity(intent);
```

In the SecondActivity, I want to have something like this:

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
```

The problem here is that I already extended "View" in my SecondActivity so my code above will not work in SecondActivity as I need to extend "Activity" to make intents work. How do I solve this? I guess it is by making another class extending Activity, but if I do that, what should I do to send things from my ThirdActivity to my SecondActivity?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class)
                      .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I am not sure what I should do here. Does this code make it possible to send this to Another class without extending it with "Activity"?

Comment: is the "context" a Context, so I need to initalize Context context at first? I have only been programming for a few months. :P

Comment: yeah, you can initialize it and use it or add your context directly in the method